# Check if key exists in Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a to-do list with task due date as an optional field, so I need to check if some tasks have dueDate and add it as a subtitle based on that. How can I check if a field exists inside a doc in a StreamBuilder?

```
class _TaskListState extends State<TaskList> {
  var myStream;
  @override
  void initState() {
    myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tasks')
        .doc(widget.uid)
        .collection('mytasks')
        .snapshots();

    super.initState();
  }

  ...

  void _updateTaskDesc(
      dynamic currTask, String newDesc, DateTime newDate, TimeOfDay newTime) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tasks')
        .doc(widget.uid)
        .collection('mytasks')
        .doc(currTask['id'])
        .update({
      'desc': newDesc,
      'dueDate': newDate.toString(),
      'dueTime': newTime.toString(),
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: myStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                height: 100, width: 100, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        } else {
          final docs = snapshot.data.docs;
          bool hasDateTime = ????? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              final currTask = docs[index];
              return InkWell(
                highlightColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                splashColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                onLongPress: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (bCtx) {
                      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                      return TaskOptions(_updateTaskDesc,
                          () => _updateHasImage(docs[index]), currTask);
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Dismissible(
                  direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  onDismissed: (_) async {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('tasks')
                        .doc(widget.uid)
                        .collection('mytasks')
                        .doc(currTask['id'])
                        .delete();

                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text("${currTask['desc']} dismissed"),
                        action: SnackBarAction(
                          label: 'Undo',
                          onPressed: () {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection("tasks")
                                .doc(widget.uid)
                                .collection("mytasks")
                                .doc(currTask['id'])
                                .set({
                              "desc": currTask['desc'],
                              "id": currTask['id'],
                              "isDone": currTask['isDone'],
                              "hasImage": currTask['hasImage'],
                            });
                            try {
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection("tasks")
                                  .doc(widget.uid)
                                  .collection("mytasks")
                                  .doc(currTask['id'])
                                  .update({
                                "dueDate": currTask['dueDate'],
                                "dueTime": currTask['dueTime'],
                              });
                            } catch (e) {}
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    ...
                    subtitle: Text(hasDateTime
                        ? DateFormat('dd/MM')
                            .format(DateTime.parse(currTask['dueDate']))
                        : ''),
                    ...
```

I saw that a `containsKey('key')` method works for some people but I get NoSuchMethod when I try that. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The single document is just a normal Dart [Map](https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/Map-class.html), so you can check if a key exists or not using [containsKey](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Map/containsKey.html) method.

So you condition becomes the following:

```
bool hasDateTime = currTask.containsKey('dueDate`);
```

**NOTE:** In the question I can see that you are defining the condition in the wrong place which is outside the `itemBuilder` method in the `ListView` so that it is not item based and well not work because it does not make sense.

You can have it in this place:

```
...
itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
    final currTask = docs[index];
    bool hasDateTime = currTask.containsKey('dueDate`);
    return InkWell(
...
```